# Symfony2: copy entities in two environments with own database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The title sounds a bit strange but I'll try to explain.

I want two environments for the customer, a production environment and a QA environment. The customer asks if it's possible to create 'products' in the QA environment and afterwards copy this to the production environment. Is this even possible?

The environment have each a own database configuration.

Comment: IMO, your question sounds much more like a database issue rather than a Symfony2 one. Have you take a look to the database clustering solution? IMO, make a database cluster is much more appropriate than trying to sync databases with some PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, you need two entity managers

```
//config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            client:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            qa:
                driver:   %database_ga_driver%
                host:     %database_ga_host%
                port:     %database_ga_port%
                dbname:   %database_ga_name%
                user:     %database_ga_user%
                password: %database_ga_password%
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:     default
                mappings:
                    AcmeProductBundle: ~
            qa:
                connection:     qa
                mappings:
                    AcmeProductBundle: ~
```

Then just program some functions to copy the objects, some operations would look like that:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qa_em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('qa');

$qa_object = $qa_em->getRepository('AcmeProductBundle:Product')->find(1);

$em->persist($qa_object);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Symfony2 problem. One possible solution for your needs here is to create a 'draft' entity that can be then turned into a 'real' entity, but you would do this in your production environment.

This draft entity can be exactly like the real one, but will reside in its own table, etc. Then add some kind of process that allows the user to turn a 'draft' into a 'real' entity, possibly via a service (as if at some point you cant to add/remove functionality in one of said entities, you have a centralised point where to make adaptations).

But, in reality, the most simple way is to add a 'draft' flag to your real entitiy, and filter by this flag when necessary.